# SQL join on two columns with different format

Tags: sql

I have a column in `TABLE1` with Numbers

```
      Id
      4-157-802 
      354-332
      33-989-083
      5-525-688
```

I have a column in `TABLE2` with same numbers but without the dash (-)

```
      Id
      4157802 
      354332
      33989083
      5525688
```

I tried writing a join statement to join these tables based on these two columns as follows, its not working.

```
Select * from TABLE1
where
TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
and TABLE2.ID in ('5525688')
```

Need help with this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select table1.* 
from TABLE1 join table2 
on replace(TABLE1.ID,'-','') = TABLE2.ID
```

You can try this using the `replace` function.

Comment: that is exactly what the dr ordered :)